# What is 'this' as a parameter in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I have a SELECT html element which has the onchange event like this:

```
onchange="myFunction(this)"
```

What kind of object is **this** in this context?

```
function myFunction(control){
var jqObject = $(control);
...
..
var jqObject2 = jqObject.find('select.mySecondSelect')
}
```

Inside my function I get another object with jQuery (jqObject2) which represents another select HTML Element and I want to cascade this object to a similar function like myFunction(this)

So, how can I transform the jQuery object as JavaScript object but like **this** as a parameter does?

I found in some posts that calling the **jqObject.get(0)** or **jqObject[0]** is what I should need, however I don't think it is the same thing. Because with get(0) I am getting the native DOM element but not specifically as an object AFAIK.

---

### **Update**

This will be the whole scenario:

**HTML**

```
<select name="lstCountry" class="country" onchange="onCountryChange(this)">
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="MEXICO">Mexico</option>
</select>

<select name="lstState" class="state" onchange="onStateChange(this)">
....
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function onCountryChange(control){
   var oCountry = $(control);
   var oState = oCountry.closest('tr').find('select.state'); //<== oState is never empty or unspecified. I always get the object correctly.
   //do operations related to the country

   //specific case, call the onStateChange
   onStateChange(oState.get(0));  //<== Here!!
}

function onStateChange(control){
   var oState = $(control); //<== When I call this from the function onCountryChange, control is equals to unspecified. BUT not when the user really perform the onchange on the control state (select Element) manually
   //do operations related to the state
}
```

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html, http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in an `onXXX` attribute is the DOM element itself. So in this case it's the `<select>` element that the user changed. `$(control)` creates a jQuery object that contains the DOM element. Given a jQuery object that contains a collection of elements, you can use `jqObject.get(n)` or `jqObject[n]` to get the nth element in the collection. So if there's just one element in the jQuery object, `jqObject[0]` will return that element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Barmar, I tried to call my function doing this myFunction(jqObject2.get(0)) but when I go inside the function the control object should be the DOM element as an object but it gives me "unspecified". So, when I check jqObject2.get(0) gives me the HTML Element structure on the console of Chrome browser. But when I trigger the select element onchange event this will give the same element but as a 'Object' and I think this is a "JavaScript object". You know what I am missing?

Comment: `jqObject` is set inside the function, you can't use it when calling the function.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding. I mean, imagine that jqObject2 is gonna be passed into another function like myFunction does right now. It's not the same function. So, my new function, call it myFunction2(control), inside will have the same catch like myFunction(control), I mean var newObject = $(control), but control is unspecified.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding you. Edit your question and add the exact code you're asking about.

Comment: `.find()` never undefined result. If it doesn't find anything matching, it returns a jQuery object whose length is 0.

Comment: Apparently, I had a browser's cache problem. It works as you said. Thank you so much for your valuable answer and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> In JavaScript `this` always refers to the “owner” of the function we're
>   executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.
>   When we define our faithful function doSomething() in a page, its
>   owner is the page, or rather, the window object (or global object) of
>   JavaScript. An onclick property, though, is owned by the HTML element
>   it belongs to.

Via- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

And as @Barmar mentioned, `jqObject.get(0)` or `jqObject[0]` basically returns the first object from an array, `jqObject.get(1)` or `jqObject[1]` returns the second and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've already tried this and I get a "unspecified" inside my function. Look please at the question to the comment of Barmar. There I explained my behavior!

Answer (score 0):

What you found in those post is the correct thing.

The `this` in your code (*`onchange="myFunction(this)"`*) refers to the raw html element (*that the attribute is applied*).

So using `jqObject2[0]` will point to the raw html element of the followup query.